# como hago para que verifique correctamente email en login en android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, login, email, autenticación

ya hecho los pasos con Firebase para la autentificación de usuarios en el Login y en el registro,
pero hay un error en la autentificación me sale que no es valido el email, que debo verificar el email y no  me permite ingresar con usuarios ya creados desde firebase.
deigual forma tapoco me permite registrar usuarios por que ocurre lo mismo no hay . me podrían ayudar a ver si me falta algo o en que me estoy equivocando.
ya tengo el archivo jar de firebase
en gradle tambien estan las dependencias competas

gracias.

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_ProyectoTest11)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    btn_sign_up.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this, SignUpActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }

    btn_log_in.setOnClickListener {
        doLogin()
    }
}

private fun doLogin() {
    if (tv_username.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
        tv_username.error = "Por favor ingrese email"
        tv_username.requestFocus()
        return
    }
    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(tv_username.text.toString()).matches()) {
        tv_username.error = "Por favor ingrese  email valido"
        tv_username.requestFocus()
        return
    }
    if (tv_password.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
        tv_password.error = "Por favor ingrese  contraseña valida"
        tv_password.requestFocus()
        return
    }
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(tv_username.text.toString(), tv_password.text.toString())
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val user = auth.currentUser
                updateUI(user)
            } else {

                updateUI(null)
            }
        }
}


public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    updateUI(currentUser)
}

private fun updateUI(currentUser: FirebaseUser?) {

    if (currentUser != null) {
        if (currentUser.isEmailVerified) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, DashboardActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                baseContext, "por favor verificar su email",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
            baseContext, "Inicio fallido",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Imprime que contiene : tv_username.text.toString() al iniciar el mètodo, ese debe ser el problema

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu còdigo estas obteniendo directamente la referencia de un `EditText` o `TextView`, el còdigo es correcto pero debes asegurar que el texto que tiene `tv_username.text.toString()` sea un email vàlido.

Puedes comprobarlo imprimiendo el valor al inicio de tu funciòn.

```
private fun doLogin() {
 println("El valor de tv_username es: " + tv_username.text.toString())
 ...
 ...
 ...
}
```